# form library permissions

Tags: 2007, libraries, infopath

Is there a way to set the permissions on a form library, so that anybody can submit the info path form to the library, but only a select few can view it, after its been submitted?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure these with a workflow now. Check my post [Configure Item Level Permissions for Document Libraries – Part 2 – SharePoint 2010 edition](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2010/03/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries-part-2/). Basically a SPD workflow is triggered when form is created and it assigns appropriate privileges to users.

You can also solve the problem with event receivers, but you need to develop your own feature with custom code to solve it.

**EDIT:** In case you are looking for 2007 version solution check my post about that here: [Configure Item Level Permissions for Document Libraries](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2009/07/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries/). This is a custom feature you can deploy to your SharePoint. This is not ideal, it would be much better to create it as event handler but it might help you solve your problem.

Comment: That would be great, but we're on 2007

Comment: Oups, sorry... But I have solution for v2007 as well.